# Accessing python namedtuple _fields from other modules

Tags: python, namedtuple

I want to be able to get the length of the _fields member of a namedtuple from another module. However, it is flagged as protected.

The workaround I have is as follows:

```py
MyTuple = namedtuple(
    'MyTuple', 
    'a b'
)
"""MyTuple description

Attributes:
    a (float): A descrip
    b (float): B descrip
"""
NUM_MY_TUPLE_FIELDS = len(MyTuple._fields)
```

Then I import NUM_MY_TUPLE_FIELDS from the external module.

I was trying to find a way to make the functionality part of the class, such as to extend the namedtuple with a __len__ method. Is there a more pythonic way to get the number of fields in a namedtuple from an external module?

Updated to show the autodoc comments. The protected warning is seen in PyCharm. Originally, in the external module I simply imported MyTuple, then used:

```
x = len(MyTuple._fields)
```

I tried the following suggestion and thought it was going to work, but I get the following: TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len().

```py
class MyTuple(typing.MyTuple):
    a: float
    b: float
    """MyTuple doc

    Attributes:
        a (float): A doc
        b (float): B doc
    """
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._fields)

fmt_str = f"<L {len(MyTuple)}f"   # for struct.pack usage
print(fmt_str)
```

Comment: Could you also show the code you used before your workaround?

Comment: My `test1.py` contains `from collections import namedtuple; MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', 'a b c d e f')`. My `test2.py` contains `from test1 import MyTuple; print(len(MyTuple._fields))`. I get no errors, but `6` as output. I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: [`namedtuple` is a method, not a class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py)...

Comment: Updated original post to contain full code and noted that the protected warning is from PyCharm. I had read that namedtuple is an odd beast - a generated class? Maybe that wasn't correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use inheritance:

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'a b c d e f')): 
    """MyTuple description

    Attributes:
       a (float): A description 
       ...
    """
    @property
    def fields(self): 
        # _fields is a class level attribute and available via
        # MyTuple._fields from external modules
        return self._fields

    def __len__(self): 
        # your implementation if you need it
        return len(self._fields)
```

or use [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) if you are using python 3.5+

```
class MyTuple(typing.NamedTuple): 
   a: int
   # other fields
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to preserve the autodoc comments when using this inheritance approach. See updated 'full' code in original post.

Comment: so you want to add class-level docstring? it should work the same way as with any other class

Comment: PyCharm complains about each of the attributes: Unresolved reference 'a'

Comment: docstring should solve it. if you are using python>3.5 I recommend `typing.NamedTuple`

Comment: But PyCharm is okay with: self.a (float)      [groan]

Comment: Using the latter example worked fine. (typing.NamedTuple)  And with no PyCharm complaints or requiring a 'self.' in front of the attributes.

Comment: It looked like PyCharm was happy, but got an error when running. See revised original post.

Comment: it is not common to call `len(MyTuple)` to say the least. You shold call `len` func of an instance of class  `len(MyTuple())`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197512/discussion-between-e-holder-and-alexey).

Comment: Doh! That was a graceful response. However, instantiation of MyTuple() requires arguments. If I supply the arguments, then I would know how many there are, which is the problem in the first place.

Comment: but you can always use `len(MyTuple._fields)` in outer modules

Comment: Okay, yes! PyCharm flags that usage as protected if using collections.namedtuple, but it does NOT flag it as protected when using typing.NamedTuple. I won't call it terribly pretty, accessing an underscored member from an outside module, but it works.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. But the answer is really to use typing.NamedTuple and access the _fields member from the external class. Other elements of this answer are incorrect or suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) and just count how many parameters the `__new__` method requires:

```
import inspect
n_fields = len(inspect.signature(NTClass).parameters)
```

This works because `typing.NamedTuple` disallows overriding the `__new__` method, and that is unlikely to change due to the way it is implemented:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class NTClass(NamedTuple):
...  x: int
...  y: float
...
>>> len(inspect.signature(NTClass).parameters)
2
```

It also works for the old `collections.namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NTClass = namedtuple("NTClass", "x y")
>>> len(inspect.signature(NTClass).parameters)
2
```